# Find the hyperbola whose transverse and conjugate axes are $x+2y-3=0$ and $2x-y+4=0$, with corresponding lengths $\sqrt{2}$ and $\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections

> The equation of the transverse and conjugate axis of a hyperbola are $x+2y-3=0$ and $2x-y+4=0$, and their corresponding lengths are $\sqrt{2}$ and $\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$. Find the equation of the hyperbola:

This is attempted to solve in my reference as

$$
\frac{\big(\frac{x+2y-3}{\sqrt{5}}\big)^2}{\frac{1}{2}}-\frac{\big(\frac{2x-y+4}{\sqrt{5}}\big)^2}{\frac{1}{3}}=1\\
\frac{2(x+2y-3)^2}{5}-\frac{3(2x-y+4)^2}{5}=1
$$
I am having trouble understanding the logic behind such a substitution in the above attempt ?

Comment: Note that the axes are perpendicular, then recall the formula for the distance from a point to a line.

Comment: @Blue Alright. So the variable $x$ is the perpendicular distance of the point from x-axis, ie. $y=0$. So we are just extending that idea by replacing $y=0$ with the given line, right ?

Comment: If $d_1$ and $d_2$ are the distances of a point on the hyperbola from transverse and conjugate axis, then: $${d_1^2\over a_1^2}-{d_2^2\over a_2^2}=1,$$ where $a_1$ and $a_2$ are the half-lengths of the axes.